# jquery $(document).ready not being called after submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, turbolinks

In a Ruby on Rails 4 application I have a form which uses jQuery DatePicker (from the `jquery-ui-rails` Gem.

So I need to call

```
$('.datepicker').datepicker();
```

everytime my form is rendered.

I started with this (in my controller specific `.js.coffee` file.)

```
$ -> 
    $('.datepicker').datepicker
```

It went fine until I got the Turbolinks problem and had to change to:

```
ready = ->
    $('.datepicker').datepicker();

$(document).ready = ready
$(document).on 'page:change', ready
```

But I still have problems after hitting the submit button and there is one (or more) errors, so the form is re-rendered but none of the handlers (`document.ready` and `document.on page:change`) are called.

I've put this code in `application.js`

```
$(function(){
    console.log("application.js -> ready")
})
```

and I can see in the console that this is being called, but the functions defined in the controller specific .js file are not.

All the files seems to be loaded correctly (they have a `<script>` line in the `<header>` section; and appear in Chrome's Sources tab.

Comment: I'm not clear on the syntax above, but from a javascript/jquery perspective `$(document).ready = ready` doesn't register a function to call on the ready event, it clobbers the `ready` function that you are supposed to invoke to register a listener.

Comment: @MikeEdwards, please make your comment a response, so I can check it as the answer! I needed to remove the `=` sign...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not clear on the syntax above, but from a javascript/jquery perspective:

```
$(document).ready = ready
```

This doesn't register a function to call on the ready event, it clobbers the ready function that you are supposed to invoke to register a listener.

Comment: Just to make it clear, changing my line to: `$(document).ready ready` solved my problem.